# How to send Image or file to the external API using HTTP Client?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-http-client

I have an API to save images and files

this is the code to save the image request from the API

```
$file = $request->file('gambar');
$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->storeAs('images/berita', $fileName);

$berita = new Berita;
$berita->judul = $request->judul;
$berita->kategori_id = $request->kategori_id;
$berita->isi = $request->isi;
$berita->gambar = $fileName;
$berita->tgl = $request->tgl;
$berita->user_id = $request->user_id;
$berita->save();

return response()->json([
    'message' => 'Data berita Added Successfully!',
    'Added berita' => $berita
], Response::HTTP_OK);
```

Then on the client side, I'm using HTTP Client from Laravel to POST the data to the API. And here's the code.

```
$Berita = Http::withToken('xxx')
      ->attach('attachment', file_get_contents($request->file('gambar')))
      ->post('https://api.xxx.my.id/xxx', [
           'judul' => $request->judul,
           'kategori_id' => $request->kategori_id,
           'isi' => $request->isi,
           'gambar' => file_get_contents($request->file('gambar')),
           'tgl' => $request->tgl,
           'user_id' => $request->user_id
      ]);

return $Berita;
```

All the data send successfully, except the `gambar` which contains the image that i sent. It says that in my API validation.

```
The gambar must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png.
```

It thought that means the image that i send is sent as a string, so it didn't receive it as a file.

By the way, here's the Laravel documentation about HTTP Client: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#multi-part-requests

Does anyone knows how to correctly using it? I think i've misused it.

Comment: $request->file('gambar') this should give you the uploaded file to your app.

Comment: @gguney Result is the same, it still said, `The gambar must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png.`

Comment: What is your uploaded file? Is it image jpg etc.? Can you share API code for validation? I think your main problem is validation.

Comment: @gguney `'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:3072'` this is my validation on API for `gambar`

Comment: So you must send jpeg,jpg or png and it can't pass 3072 size (I guess it is ~3mb).  Can you try a small size? and use jpg jpeg etc? Also, can you try removing validation for gambar to check if it is working without validation?

Comment: @gguney And now it says that `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null` error on my API Code line 2

Comment: Did you completely remove from you validation? You have to put it if you are using "$request->vadalited()" Can you also share you api validation code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242898/discussion-between-decrager-and-gguney).

Answer (score 2):

This is because the server cannot read your data.

You should send the data using the **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** content type, you can achieve this as [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#sending-form-url-encoded-requests) says:

```
$response = Http::asForm()->post('http://example.com/users', [
    'name' => 'Sara',
    'role' => 'Privacy Consultant',
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem with attachment.

```
  return Http::withToken('xxx')
          ->attach('gambar', file_get_contents($request->file('gambar')), , 'gambar.png')
          ->post('https://api.xxx.my.id/xxx', [
               'judul' => $request->judul,
               'kategori_id' => $request->kategori_id,
               'isi' => $request->isi,
               'tgl' => $request->tgl,
               'user_id' => $request->user_id
          ]);
```

or

```
return Http::withToken('xxx')
      ->attach('gambar', $request->file('gambar'), 'gambar.png')
      ->post('https://api.xxx.my.id/xxx', [
           'judul' => $request->judul,
           'kategori_id' => $request->kategori_id,
           'isi' => $request->isi,
           'tgl' => $request->tgl,
           'user_id' => $request->user_id
      ]);
```